# "All the four types of meat consumption is"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, ielts

In an IELTS essay where I need to analyze the trends in this chart, I wrote:

> *In the future (this test was given in 2007 I wanted to act like a test taker at the time), **all the four types** of meat consumption **is** forecast to fall slightly by December 2012.*

Grammarly corrects it as:

1. Write **all four types** instead of **all the four types**.
   But if I write it the way Grammarly suggests, it sounds like there are "four types of consumption", while it should be "four types of meat".
2. Write **are** instead of **is**. However, the main subject is **consumption** which is singular.

I don't know what's wrong with my version. Could you clear this up for me, please?

[image]

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic, but I agree with all Grammarly's suggestions. The subject of _forecast_ is _four types_, so it should be _are_.

Comment: Consumption of all four types of meat is projected to decline slightly.  This is too much of a mouthful: "forecast to witness a projection of a slight fall".  The consumption itself doesn't "witness a projection".  It is projected to witness (i.e. undergo or show) a slight fall ...

Comment: "**Meat's consumption**" **is wrong**, even though it may be technically grammatical, the "meat consumption" is not possessive, it isn't the meat that is doing the consumption, it isn't the meat that belongs to consumption. Look at the title, it has "Meat & Poultry consumption” do you think an English exam would have an ungrammatical title? You could say **the consumption of meat**

Comment: Thank you all a lot. After reading your suggestions, I think there's only one main question left, which is "all the four types..." or "all four types...". I don't see any difference here.

Comment: Also, if this is asking for proofreading, I honestly wonder how I should have asked the questions.

Comment: In the edit I deleted the 3rd question, if the issues are narrowed down, two at the most, the question is on-topic. You've shared your research and you've also  explained your confusion.

Comment: While I agree that _types_ going with _are_ is correct here, changing the sentence this way makes it sound awkward to me because it's **the consumption of a meat type** that  is forecast to fall, not **the type of consumption** that is forecast to fall.

Comment: @KenAdams the problem is that no English speaker is going to read "all the four types of meat consumption" as you intend (ie. with "consumption" as the main subject and "all the four types of meat" as an object). *Consumption of all four types of meat / meat types* on the other hand makes it far clearer.

Comment: I agree with Maciej. "All the four types of meat consumption" means "all of the four ways/methods in which meat can be consumed."